# I can't get a native resolution of 1920x1080 on 11.10 (AOC f22 on a Nvidia Geforce GTS 450)

Tags: resolution, screen

I have a problem were the highest resolution I can get is 1360x769, this is a 22 inch LCD monitor with a native resolution of 1920x1080_60 I have tried numerous drivers but nothing changed I tried editing the xorg.conf scipt with no success (I am a noob with linux though). Running many commands in terminal witch I got from people with similar problems only gives me errors like "Failed to get size of gamma for output default. I get edid checksum is invalid error on boot down also.
I think there maybe a communication problem between my screens EDID and ubuntu although xp and windows 7 detect my screen without any errors and automatically set native resolution. also when I am installing ubuntu I get a horrible screen flashing every few seconds until I have installed the nvidia driver. pc specks if it helps x64 os, mainboard N68PV-GS, 4 gig ram, AMD Phenom(tm) 9350e Quad-Core Processor × 4, Nvidia Geforce gts450 512mb, hard drives set up in a onboard nvidia raid array striped. realy need to get a better resolution, 1360x769 does not look nice on a 22 inch screen. ty

Comment: I am Happy to say my problem is solved for some reason the software could not figure some things out for it's self so to fix my problem I edited xorg.conf file, Under section "monitor" i edited line horizsync to 28.0-72.0 and vertrefresh to 43.0-72.0. Why this isn't set up properly when the driver is installed I don't know so any one having similar problems up the horizsync but make sure it has a bandwith to choose from otherwise you might just get no screen at all.

Answer (score 1):

Following options from *X Config Options* chapter of the proprietary Nvidia driver documentation might be helpful:

```
Option "IgnoreEDIDChecksum" "string"
```

This option forces the X driver to accept an EDID even if the checksum is invalid. You may specify a comma separated list of display names. [...]

```
Option "UseEdidFreqs" "False"
```

This option controls whether the NVIDIA X driver will use the HorizSync and VertRefresh ranges given in a display device's EDID, if any. [...]

```
Option "ModeValidation" "string"
```

This option provides fine-grained control over each stage of the mode validation pipeline, disabling individual mode validation checks. This option should only very rarely be used. [...]

http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/295.20/README/xconfigoptions.html

But be careful and don't try all possible options, just because they sound interesting.